# The specified file path does not exist. Google Hangouts will not launch

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-hangouts

Whenever I try to launch Google hangouts (even from inbox) I get

[image].

But if I go to:

> C:\Program Files **(x86)**\Google\Chrome\Application

There is a file called `chrome.exe`

There is no `\Google` folder in `C:\program Files\`

I'm running Chrome 52 on Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome?

Comment: Can I do that without losing any data?

Comment: Yeah i mean all you data should be stored in your google account